# React shouldComponentUpdate() does not prevent re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the `ThreeDisplay` React component shown below for holding a WebGL/Three.js canvas (the canvas itself is not part of the component, it gets appended to the container `div` by an initialization script).

I want the component only to update after every `RUN` and `UPDATE` action. Those actions get dispatched by the parent component of `ThreeDisplay`.

Now for some reason, the component also gets updated/re-rendered if the last action was `FADE_COLOR` or `SWITCH_COLOR`. Those actions get dispatched by ThreeDisplay, they are triggered by mouse events, as shown in the code below.

I'm trying to use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to update only after the aforementioned actions. But for some reason, this does not prevent the component to re-render on every mouse event.

The full code of my application/prototype can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/lysigk/react-redux-three)

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {connect} from 'react-redux'

    import {fadeColor, switchColor} from '../actions'

    class ThreeDisplay extends React.Component {
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
            const shouldUpdate =
                nextProps.lastAction === 'RUN' || nextProps.lastAction === 'UPDATE'

            if (!shouldUpdate) {
                console.log('ThreeDisplay will not update on ' + nextProps.lastAction)
            }

            return shouldUpdate
        }

        componentWillUpdate() {
            // This gets logged even if lastAction ist not 'RUN' or 'UPDATE'
            console.log('ThreeDisplay will update on ' + this.props.lastAction)
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div
                    id="container"
                    className={
                        this.props.running
                            ? 'three-display'
                            : 'three-display hidden'
                    }
                    onClick={this.props.switchColor}
                    onMouseMove={this.props.fadeColor}
                />
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            running: state.running,
            lastAction: state.lastAction
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchTopProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            fadeColor: e => dispatch(fadeColor(e)),
            switchColor: () => dispatch(switchColor())
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchTopProps)(ThreeDisplay)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this expression

```
const shouldUpdate = nextProps.lastAction === 'RUN' || 'UPDATE'
```

If `nextProps.lastAction === 'RUN'` is false, then the code evaluates the other branch of the OR, i.e. just the `'UPDATE'` string, which is always true, thus `shouldUpdate` will always be true.

Replace it with

```
const shouldUpdate = nextProps.lastAction === 'RUN'
  || nextProps.lastAction ===  'UPDATE'
```

Comment: The problem is that in `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` your props aren't updated,  so you need to console.log nextProps.lastAction instead and you'll see that it works after doing the change @Maluen posted.